# R doesn't display percentages when trying to build a pie chart

Tags: r, error-handling, compiler-errors, pie-chart

This is the code I wrote :

```
gender=Survey$`To_which_gender_you_identify_the_most?`
gender<-as.factor(gender)
count=c("Prefer not to say","Male","Female")
pie(table(gender),labels=c(paste0(count)))
```

I'm trying to create a pie chart that displays percentages but the percentages don't show.
Sample data

[image]

dput

```
> dput(head(Survey[1:4]))
structure(list(Horodateur = structure(c(1619171956.596, 1619172695.039, 
1619173104.83, 1619174548.534, 1619174557.538, 1619174735.457
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), `To_which_gender_you_identify_the_most?` = c("Male", 
"Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female"), What_is_your_age_group = c("[18-24[", 
"[10,18[", "[18-24[", "[18-24[", "[18-24[", "[25,34["), How_much_time_do_you_spend_on_social_media = c("1-5 hours", 
"1-5 hours", ">10 hours", "5-10 hours", "5-10 hours", "1-5 hours"
)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
>
```

Comment: make sure you have defined count (as a character vector)

Comment: @rawr I did define count=c("Prefer not to say", "Male","Female") but I don't get the percentages, the error is gone though.

Comment: @rawr I edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated.**
Based on the updated example data, this code will produce pie chart labeled with percentages as requested.

```
#your example data
Survey<-structure(list(
    Horodateur = structure(c(1619171956.596, 1619172695.039, 1619173104.83, 1619174548.534, 1619174557.538, 1619174735.457), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    `To_which_gender_you_identify_the_most?` = c("Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female"),
    What_is_your_age_group = c("[18-24[", "[10,18[", "[18-24[", "[18-24[", "[18-24[", "[25,34["), 
    How_much_time_do_you_spend_on_social_media = c("1-5 hours", "1-5 hours", ">10 hours", "5-10 hours", "5-10 hours", "1-5 hours")), 
row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
#make a dataframe of a gender table
gender<-data.frame(table(Survey$`To_which_gender_you_identify_the_most?`))
#add a percentages to the labels. Don't use 'count' to label unless you are sure it mataches the order of your data. More on that below. 
pie(gender$Freq,labels=c(paste0(gender$Var1," ",round(100*gender$Freq/length(Survey$`To_which_gender_you_identify_the_most?`), digits = 0),"%")))
```

Result:[image: example of pie chart in R specific to this question]

**Original.**
You would need to add some kind of percent calculation to your `label=` within `pie()`. All your current code is doing is labeling  the pie chart with the character vector called `count`. Try this instead:

```
#make a dataframe out of the table of your gender object  
your_table<-data.frame(table(gender))
#add a percentages to the labels. Don't use 'count' to label unless you are sure it mataches the order of your data. More on that below. 
pie(your_table$Freq,labels=c(paste0(your_table$gender," ",round(100*your_table$Freq/length(gender), digits = 0),"%")))
```

One thing to be careful of in your original code is that you are applying labels based on the vector called `count`, but the factor order in the `gender` object may or may not match. Let me show you how this could mislabel your pie().

```
#This is an example of how you might mislabel your data.
Survey<-data.frame(`To_which_gender_you_identify_the_most?`=c("Female","Male","Female","Male","Female", "Prefer not to say"))
gender=Survey$`To_which_gender_you_identify_the_most`
gender<-as.factor(gender)
count=c("Prefer not to say","Male","Female")
your_table<-data.frame(table(gender))
pie(your_table$Freq,labels=c(paste0(count," ",round(100*your_table$Freq/length(gender), digits = 0),"%")))
```

Note all the percentage labels are correct, but the text labels from `count` are in the wrong order in this example image.[image: mislabeled pie chart created in R]

Comment: @SAnalyst I got the wrong percentages when applying that first chunk of good. This is a snippet of the dataset ```` > dput(head(Survey$To_which_gender_you_identify_the_most?))
structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Female", "Male", 
"Prefer not to say,"), class = "factor")````

Comment: Can you please edit your original question again with sample data?

Comment: I added a a picture of the dataframe and a dput as a snippet